# How to show parent taxonomy using get_the_terms?

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I have registered one custom taxonomy. I am using this code to show this taxonomy on `single.php`.

But it shows parent and child terms as well.

```
function showorganisation()
{
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'organization');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_link = get_term_link($term, 'organization');
        if (is_wp_error($term_link))
            continue;
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
}
```

How can I make it show parent terms only?

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_terms()` gives you an array of [WP_Term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects. The object has `parent` (int) property, which tells you, if the term is a child and has a parent term or not.

This means that in your loop you can skip child terms with a simple `if` statement.

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {

  // Is it a child term?
  if ( $term->parent ) {
    continue;
  }

  // code...

}
```